# What can be improved in this SQL schema?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, schema

I'm trying to design a database for shoe catalogue, but I'm confused with storing info about sizes: I have no idea what is the best way to store sizes per each item. This is my first schema and I tried to solve this problem by making id per each item and item_id per each unique item (with different size).
[image]

So, the question is: what can I improve to make this work better and faster? (table Products will contain more than 2 - 3 mils) And is it the best way to store sizes?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Make sure to have an index on products.size_id (and indexes on other fields you want to use in search criteria.)

Answer (score 1):

The performance depends on queries and application type (OLTP or OLAP). You need also index all foreign key columns at least.

The following tables seems to be required: `models` (contains product common specifications) and `product_shops` (M:M).

Answer (score 1):

Well I think there are a few things that needs to be improved.

1. The `size_id, sport_id, vendor_id, shop_id` in the `Products` table shouldn't exist. If you want to keep the current design, you should have the `product_id` in the other respective tables . Neither solution satisfies the logic completely in my opinion but it's better to have multiple rows with `product_id`s in the `Sizes` table then `size_id`s in `Products` table. You would really want to keep the products rows in the `Products` table not replicated because of other properties / foreign keys. (So the same principal applies to `Categories` as an example.) Otherwise you'd have the same Product row replicated with different gender / group / size / shop / vendor / sport so N rows majorly sharing the data. Extracting the `product_id` to the other tables instead would make your joins more efficient and you'll be able to filter stuff like 'Shoes with size 37' more efficiently. **Or better yet, create another table called Product - ensure you have all of the columns you want to have per product.**
2. Clicks / Views - if they are counts you probably should remove them out of the `Products` table, they are more analytics fields rather than the products. Move to their own (Analytics?) table with the `product_id`.
3. You probably typo'ed the `genger_id` - in the table - that should be `gender_id`. Same rule applies as point 1.
4. If the Groups / Categories can be denormalized (ex: Group: Shoe, Category: Sports Shoe) and you don't have enough in one of these, I suggest you to denormalize and merge these two.
5. As the comments also suggested, you should definitely index the foreign key fields.